# NodeJS Parser with VueJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, peg

I have a task - parsing data of this type `("Query1" OR "Query2") AND ("Quesy3" OR "Query4")`

I am using [TsPeg](https://github.com/EoinDavey/tsPEG) for this. Everything worked out, but how can you use the `parse()` method of library inside a Vue project?

Simply put, I need to pull out a method available in **Node.js** in **VueJS**

Comment: ? `import {} from ""` - the limit nodejs might be an issue if you need access to more than just v8 in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put parser as `~/modules/parser.js` where `~/` is root dir for vue.
Then you can simply import and use in your vue file's `<script></script>` tag

```js
import { sum } from '~/modules/parser.js'
```